# Why in this problem I had to take the average of the electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

> On an electrically charged soap bubble, acts an electric force
>   outwards. We are given the total charge of the bubble, $Q$, and its
>   radius, $R$. What is the value of the total force, acting to move one
>   half of the bubble away from the other?

I understood the solution, besides a small point that disturbs me -

They said $dF=Edq$ and then $E=\frac\sigma{2\epsilon_0}$. It seems like they took the average of the electric field inside and outside the surface of the bubble (which is, respectively, $0$ and $\frac\sigma{\epsilon_0}$).

Is this always done when the electric field on a surface is to be used in a calculation?

Comment: This is confusing.  Is there a charge or source inside the bubble?  Why is the field zero outside the bubble?  If you move far enough away, the electric field should look no different than that from a point charge.

Comment: @honeste_vivere There is no charge source inside the bubble. The bubble is like a charged spherical shell.
By guass, there is 0 electric field inside it.

Comment: Oh, whoops... I read that part in your parentheses backwards.  That is my fault.  I agree with your statement now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like they took the average of the electric field inside and outside the surface of the bubble (which is, respectively, $0$ and $\frac\sigma{\epsilon_0}$).

If you gave the surface some thickness (but still thin) and a uniform volume charge density then the electric field is $0$ inside and $\frac\sigma{\epsilon_0}$ outside and changes roughly linearly (when the shell is thin) between the inside and the outside surface.

> Is this always done when the electric field on a surface is to be used in a calculation?

Its always that you make a singular density (whether volume, surface or line charge density) act like a limit of a nicer (and finite) volume charge densities. Whether its as simple as an average depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field of a spherical shell with uniform surface charge density $\sigma$ close to its surface is $E=0$ inside the shell and $E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$ radially outward outside the shell.

If you consider an element of surface area $dA$, the electric field from this element is $E_1=\sigma/2\epsilon_0$ directed both radially inward and outward.

The electric field $E_2$ due to the rest of the shell must combine with $E_1$ to give the field $E$ due to the whole shell - ie $E=E_1+E_2$. So we must have $E_2=-E_1$ inside the shell (giving a total field of $0$ here) and $E_2=E_1$ outside the shell (giving a total field of $E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$ here).

The external force on the element under consideration is $dF=E_2dq$ where $dq=\sigma dA$ is the charge on the surface element. We use $E_2$ here and not $E$ because charges do not exert forces on themselves. Of course the element has internal forces, which might make it expand or contract, but these forces cannot make the COM of the element move.